# I am trying to add specific handlers and alertStyles to my alerts, but I am using a global alert which doesn't have a handler

Tags: swift, uialertaction

Is there any separate global function to add a different style and a different handler for alerts?
My function from `AppDelegate` looks like this:

```
static func showAlertView(vc : UIViewController, titleString : String , messageString: String) ->()
 {
   let alertView = UIAlertController(title: titleString, message: messageString, preferredStyle: .alert)

   let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: .cancel) { (alert) in
      vc.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
     alertView.addAction(alertAction)
     vc.present(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean by different style and different handler? If by different handler you mean another one, you can anytime add another action to your `alertView`, and if by style you mean action style [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertaction/style) are the currently supported styles.

Comment: Yes, the best method is to add another alert in my code whenever I need to add a specific handler.. because the global function doesn’t let me add a handler.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add more parameters to your function. In the code below I've added the following: `controllerStyle` for UIAlertController, `actionStyle` for UIAlertAction and `action` for UIAlertAction handler.

```
static func showAlertView(vc : UIViewController, titleString : String , messageString: String, controllerStyle: UIAlertController.Style = .alert, actionStyle: UIAlertAction.Style = .cancel, action:  @escaping () -> () = {}) {
    let alertView = UIAlertController(title: titleString, message: messageString, preferredStyle: controllerStyle)
    let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: .cancel) { (alert) in
        if action == {} {
            vc.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            action()
        }
    }
    alertView.addAction(alertAction)
    vc.present(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Isn't it the same as what OP added? Simply creating a method is not adding any difference to it.

Comment: Not it is not. OP wanted more configurations in her method which were missing from the code she shared. I believe she knew how to add `controllerStyle` and `actionStyle` yet she was not aware that a method could be passed as a variable to a function. Which is something I added in my answer.

Comment: Thank you!  What I wanted to know is if I can use only one global alert function on the entire project, even if I have sometimes handlers or other styles for any aletrs..But I think that where I have specific handlers I have to add another alert.

Comment: Well that is true. This solution only works for alert controllers with 1 customizable action. If you were to add more then you'll have to have specific handlers.